# Where can I find parameters of the query in SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, parameters, sql-server-profiler

I use SQL Server Profiler to tune up a database. I can see SQL queries in `TextData` column, but these queries are parametrized and I don't see values of these parametres.

For example:

```
DELETE [dbo].[My Table]
WHERE ([Id] = @0)
```

Where can I find parametres of the query in SQL Server Profiler?

Can I copy the SQL query with the parametres filled in from SQL Server Profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Query with respected params from `RPC COMPLETED` event of SQL Profiler.

Observe the below image. In the Code below you can find parameters of the Query after `Output` Keyword like `10252,N'Y', N'Y'` respectively of params @P0, @P1, @P2 of the Query.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the params in my SQL Profiler. The problem was that I used TSQL_Locks template. Know I have chosen Standard template and I can see the params. Thanks.